# Determine all chances of victory in a car race

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Imagine a car racing championship (like Formula 1) made up of 13 drivers. The order of arrival score is defined as:

```
1st place: 23 points
2nd place: 20 points
3rd place: 18 points
4th place: 16 points
5th place: 15 points
6th place: 14 points
7th place: 13 points
8th place: 12 points
9th place: 11 points
10th place: 10 points
11th place: 9 points
12th place: 8 points
13th place: 7 points
```

The points are added for each pilot according to their finishing position. At the end of 4 races, whoever has the most points wins the championship. After the first two races, the partial result is:

```
| DRIVER   | RACE 01   | RACE 02   | RACE 03  | RACE 04  | POINTS    |
|----------|-----------|-----------|----------|----------|-----------|
|     A    |     20    |     23    |          |          |     43    |
|     B    |     18    |     18    |          |          |     36    |
|     C    |     15    |     20    |          |          |     35    |
|     D    |     23    |     11    |          |          |     34    |
|     E    |     14    |     15    |          |          |     29    |
|     F    |     13    |     13    |          |          |     26    |
|     G    |     11    |     15    |          |          |     26    |
|     H    |     16    |     9     |          |          |     25    |
|     I    |     12    |     12    |          |          |     24    |
|     J    |     8     |     16    |          |          |     24    |
|     K    |     7     |     10    |          |          |     17    |
|     L    |     9     |     8     |          |          |     17    |
|     M    |     10    |     0     |          |          |     10    |
```

Considering that no driver misses the last two stages, and the chances of victory or any other result are equal to all drivers, what are the possible combinations for each driver to be champion?

In other words, what are the minimum finishing positions that driver A needs to finish to be champion? And pilot B? And so on.

An example is the case in Formula 1 at the end of the 2008 championship, when driver Lewis Hamilton was in the first place and Felipe Massa in second in the standings. Observe the text taken from a news item of the time:

> *With five points ahead of Felipe Massa in the championship (84 to 79), Lewis Hamilton needs to make six more than the Brazilian in the
> Chinese Grand Prix. In other words, in case of victory, the Englishman
> needs to hope that the Ferrari driver will reach below fifth
> position.*

I'm trying to do some possibilities "by my hand" but this process can be enormous. I'm trying making this on R but I couldn't move forward.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define "minimum finishing position for A to win"? Is it "regardless of whatever his opponents do" (which is how your question seems to be phrased), or it is "with opponents finishing in a certain manner (which is how the news item text is phrased).

Comment: I came to the conclusion, for example, that for driver A to win, regardless of the result of the other drivers, he only needs to get 2 second places.

My question is: how can I automate this analysis mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following cases:

- If the driver is currently the best, then they needs to maintain their lead over the second best, and so we can determine how many points they can give up (and then distribute that across different races as desired.
- If the driver is not currently the best, then they will need to win the best, who we may assume is first in a race that the driver doesn't win, or second in a race that the driver wins. This tells us the minimum number of first place finishes that are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already think this way. But mathematically and, after automate using some code, how can I do?